# Null Object Problem

Tags: javascript

I am using this JS script for multiple country selection and I get an error from firebug.

```
selObj is null
[Break on this error] selObj.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','');
```

The relevant code is this:

```
function populateCountry(idName) {
 var countryLineArray = country.split('|'); // Split into lines

 var selObj = document.getElementById(idName);

 selObj.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','');
 selObj.selectedIndex = 0;


 for (var loop = 0; loop < countryLineArray.length; loop++) {

 lineArray = countryLineArray[loop].split(':');

 countryCode = TrimString(lineArray[0]);
```

The full script [can be found here](http://javascript.internet.com/forms/country-state-drop-down.html).

This is how I use it in my HTML:

```
<select id="billCountrySelect" onchange="updateState('billCountrySelect')" name="bill_country">
```

What is the problem. I am passing it correct parameters??

Comment: since you're  not giving the error being reported, we can't help.

Comment: Its the first thing in my question?? selObj is null.

Comment: Actually, you're calling the updateState method in your code, but you list the populateCountry method as being the source of the problem. I don't see an updateState method in the code in the link you provided. Is it really erroring out in populateCountry or in updateState? If it's updateState, could you provide that source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a cursory glance, it appears that in

```
var selObj = document.getElementById(idName);
```

`document.getElementById(idName)` is not returning anything (or more precisely returning `null`).

My *guess* is that the value of `idName` is not matching.  I would start by ensuring exactly what is the value of this variable immediately before the `document.getElement` statement (I would also check for non-printing characters just to be thorough).